# Why can a system energy defined by entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, temperature, entropy

Energy define as ([wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_minimum_energy#:%7E:text=multicomponent%20system,%20the%20internal%20energy%20may%20be%20written) minimum energy of system in last section)

$E=ST -PV+\mu N$

$P$ is pressure and $V$ is volume, $Ν$  is the number of particles in the gas.

Entropy $S$ measure as the log of possible microstates of system*Boltzmann constant. I always stick at this point. What can be relation of possible microstate with energy?

If it regard with average of energy distribution then may sense but what relationship between total possible state

Comment: can you give a link for the formula? http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/temper2.html

Comment: The entropy does not take into account the number of all *possible* microstates, but the number of all *accessible* micro states. Do you understand the difference?

Comment: @anna v Wiki page Principle of minimum energy

Comment: @semoi can you give examples

Comment: there is no such simple relation there, it is either partial dfferentials or specific examples.

Comment: in the last section of wiki this equation is present. I neglect the pressure and friction energy from that equation because I am not interested in them

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_minimum_energy#:~:text=multicomponent%20system,%20the%20internal%20energy%20may%20be%20written: if you are using Chrome the line will be highlighted

Comment: multicomponent system, the internal energy may be written:

Comment: @anna v Search the aboveine on page

Comment: I am sorry, but this is a physics site, in physics we do not ignore mathematical functions because we are not interested in them!!!  One has **to show** they are zero. Your function is invalid and the question has no meaning. I vote to close..

Comment: @anna v agree, now I correct the question still question is same how entropy is related with energy. I have already defined the entropy which related with multiplicity (possible micro states) of system

Comment: Note that the Greek letter you wanted is "Mu", not "Miu".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temperature can be thought of as average energy per microscopic degree of freedom of the system. For example, in a gas, temperature is proportional to the average kinetic energy of the particles.

The entropy can be thought of as a measure of the number of microscopic degrees of freedom. If you imagine a discrete system of $n$ binary bits for instance, the number of states is $2^n$, so the entropy is $\log(2^n) = n$ (up to constant factors). It is more complicated when you have continuous degrees of freedom like positions of particles in a gas, but it's a similar idea.

So, number of degrees of freedom × average energy per degree of freedom = total energy contained in the microscopic degrees of freedom. To this you add the energy contributions of *macro*-scopic degrees of freedom like pressure and so on. This is a very rough argument and in statistical mechanics it is made much more mathematically rigorous, but that gives you the general idea.

Comment: I think I got my answer in conclusion thank you

Answer (score 0):

> The relationship which was originally used to [define entropy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Therm/entrop2.html#c2), $S$ is

$dS = dQ/T$

where Q is heat ,

> For the case of an isothermal process it can be evaluated simply by ΔS = Q/T.

So it is a change in entropy that is associated with energy in the form of heat

[Here you can see](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/therid.html) the differential connections between

$dU = TdS - PdV$ , where

U = internal energy,S = entropy, V = volume,T = temperature,P = pressure

This is the example of a [specific case](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_minimum_energy#:%7E:text=multicomponent%20system,%20the%20internal%20energy%20may%20be%20written) you are using

> Alternatively, suppose we have a cylinder containing an ideal gas, with cross sectional area A and a variable height x. Suppose that a weight of mass m has been placed on top of the cylinder. It presses down on the top of the cylinder with a force of mg where g is the acceleration due to gravity.

...

> . The total energy of the system at any value of x is given by the internal energy of the gas plus the potential energy of the weight:

$U=ST -PV+\mu N +mgx$

The statement of the particular example has to be taken as a whole, and you cannot take the internal energy, even ignoring the extra weight in the problem, and call it total energy in general.

The connection of the particular entropy with microstates comes from the interactions of the particles in the gas with each other and the walls (pressure), **each interaction consists of a microstate**, and depending on the problem it is counted in the statistical definition of entropy.

Comment: Thank you, you answer the question;I know the classical definition of entropy; I was looking for relationship between log(multiplicity) and energy; I think @nathan gives a good answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking some intuition into why would there be any relation between energy and entropy you should keep in mind that for some system with energy U volume V and number of particles N the system can only have certain micro-states that meet those requirements.
Now, in other words, there is some relation S(U,V,N) which can be reversed into U(S,V,N).
To get the exact relation as you have mentioned you need to define other variables such as pressure, temperature and chemical potential as the energy's partial derivatives and integrate. But I guess it isn't really the essence of what your question is about so I'll end my answer here.
Good luck!